# Windows 2008 R2 User Profile Service: unloads user profile of App Pool identity

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, user-profile, applicationpoolidentity

I am currently facing the following issue.

1. An web application is being hosted as a domain account (Account A) in IIS 7.5 windows 2008 R2.
2. Attribute "load user profile" is set to false
3. The application pool is running integrated mode with .net v2.0

When user log off (Account B) from their remote desktop sessions to the hosting server, the
User Profile service unloads (speculating) the user profile of the application pools Identity (Account A).

I understand that this issue is resolved by enabling group policy "Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff" or by setting the "load user profile" property
described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2009/11/06/a-com-server-application-may-stop-working-on-windows-server-2008.aspx).

Question:

1. Why does the user profile service unload (Account A) the app pool identity's profile, when other users (Account B) log off? NOTE: After Account B logs off no other user is remotely or physically logged into the host.
2. Is there a specific list of users/groups that the User profile service iterates through in order to unload profiles each time.

Thanks,
Brian